# Silverlight usercontrol pain

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have usercontrol in the lib MyCompany.Silverlight.dll

Namespace for it the same - MyCompany.Silverlight
Everything works, i can drag-drop control from toolbar to navigation pane.

Now i removed control from pane, changed namespace of control to MyCompany.
Compiled. When i tried to drag-drop to navigation pane i got the message -
The enumerator is not valid because the collection changed.

I DIDNT CHANGE anything except of namespace.

What the problem ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the VS. I guess an async project structure data update occurred while the designer was populating the toolbox.

Try restarting the VS and then rebuilding the solution.